# Where to put custom backend?

Tags: django

I've got an [email address based backend](http://justcramer.com/2008/08/23/logging-in-with-email-addresses-in-django/) I'm trying to use.

I've put the code in:

```
myapp /
  mymodule /
    backends.py
```

and in `settings.py` I've got

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'myapp.mymodule.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
```

but I get the error

```
Module "myapp.mymodule.backends" does not define a 
   "EmailOrUsernameModelBackend" authentication backend
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We would need to see backends.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `settings.py` and project layout look ok. You've not shown us your backends.py, so all we can do is guess why it's not working.

It might be a typo in your `backends.py` or your `settings`. Check that the name of your backend class exactly matches `EmailOrUsernameModelBackend`, including capital letters.

If you're not using the built in dev server, make sure that you've restarted it so that you're not running an older version of the code.

Comment: It must have been a typo or something, after much jigging around it started working in this configuration.